# How to iterate dictionary in "await foreach"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, iasyncenumerable

Help with a small problem...

I have a method that returns a dictionary.  I need to rewrite it in such a way that I can enumerate the result of this method using `await foreach`.  Please help me, something is not working for me at all.

It's my method:

```
public IDictionary<long, long> TransformListInDictionary(IList<string> list)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<long, long>();
    foreach (var member in list)
    {
        var idx = member.IndexOf(':');

        var key = member.Substring(0, idx);
        var value = member.Substring(idx + 1);

        result.Add(Convert.ToInt64(key), Convert.ToInt64(value));
    }
    return result;
}
```

To use a dictionary in an `await foreach` loop, this method requires a return value of `IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<long,long>>`.

Therefore, I have a question, how to rewrite the method published above is the return value.

**Why do I need it.**

I have some code which I am posting below. I'll try to describe my idea.

When the code enters the for loop, it does some work and instantiates the dictionary. Which is further processed in the foreach loop.

```
var logic = new AllLogic();

var variable = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
var randomSecundForPause = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < variable; i++)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    var dict = logic.TransformListInDictionary(list);

    //some code

    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        try
        {
            //some code

            Thread.Sleep(randomSecundForPause.Next(100000, 150000));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //some code

            Thread.Sleep(randomSecundForPause.Next(100000, 150000));
        }
    }

}
```

I would like this foreach loop to run in the background and the main code flow to go to a new iteration of the for loop.

As I understand it, I need to replace foreach with await foreach.

Comment: `Dictionary<,>` doesn't implement `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. Why do you you think you need `await foreach`? Await the result, *then* iterate over that.

Comment: In fact, there's no reason this method needs to be async (or awaitable at all). You're not using `await` anywhere, and you're not overriding something that already defines the `Task<...>` return type.

Comment: @madreflection I need to perform some actions asynchronously with the result of this method...

So far, the only thing that fits is await foreach

Comment: That has nothing to do with how you produce the result within this method.

Comment: @madreflection Yes, that's why I want to rewrite this method.

Comment: Right. Change the method to return `IDictionary<long, long>` (no Task), then iterate over that.. Do async work in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @madreflection the problem is that I want to rewrite this method in such a way that the result of the method can be used in the "await foreach" loop. I can't use a dictionary

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What you've posted is focused on the wrong aspect of the problem.

Comment: @madreflection I added a little to my question.

Comment: That's still not a [mre].

Comment: @madreflection Sorry, I added everything.

Comment: You're still not `await`ing anything. This code doesn't need to be async. You could use Theodor Zoulias's answer, sure, but there's no indication that you need to.

Comment: @madreflection But how then can I rewrite the code for my task?

Comment: @madreflection "I would like this foreach loop to run in the background and the main code flow to go to a new iteration of the for loop."

Comment: Running in the background and being async are entirely separate things. Your question is about async. Your code doesn't do any I/O and would not benefit from being async.

Comment: @madreflection Then in what direction should I look for the answer to my question?

Comment: Threading. You need a background thread. If you need need to know when it's done, you can use `Task.Run`, give it a *synchronous* method/lambda, and await that task. There are other ways, too.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably an asynchronous [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators):

```
#pragma warning disable CS1998
public async IAsyncEnumerable<KeyValuePair<long, long>> ToAsyncEnumerable(
#pragma warning restore CS1998
    IList<string> list)
{
    foreach (var member in list)
    {
        var idx = member.IndexOf(':');

        var key = member.Substring(0, idx);
        var value = member.Substring(idx + 1);

        yield return KeyValuePair.Create(Convert.ToInt64(key), Convert.ToInt64(value));
    }
}
```

The method must be `async`, it must have [`IAsyncEnumerable<X>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1) as return type, and it must contain the [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) contextual keyword.

The `#pragma warning disable CS1998` is needed in order to suppress a warning about an `async` method that lacks the `await` keyword. Without it the program will still compile, but the C# compiler will emit a warning.

Comment: The point I was making above is that this is entirely unnecessary *because* it doesn't use `await`.

Comment: @madreflection you might be right, but we don't know how the OP intends to use this method. Generic extension methods that convert `IEnumerable<T>`s to `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`s do exist in third-party libraries, like the respectable [System.Linq.Async](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/85f1eb7c53e27cccdbeee3e0b044916168843fcc/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ToAsyncEnumerable.cs#L21-L32), so it's not something completely unheard of.

Comment: We kind of do now that it's been edited, and it's still not `await`ing anything. It's all synchronous code at this point.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like this foreach loop to run in the background and the main
> code flow to go to a new iteration of the for loop.

You don't need an `await foreach`. The for loop body would not continue to the next iteration once it hits an `await` of any kind. Instead, it would **asynchronously wait** for whatever it is to finish, and only when it does will the next iteration of the for loop start.

If you want to understand it better, try running this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i} Started");
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine($"{i} Finished");
}
```

If you want the `foreach` **body** to run in the background, you need to wrap the body inside a `Task.Run(...)` call. This call would return a `Task`, so store the `Task` in a collection and `await Task.WhenAll(...)` afterwards.

Would something like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>(variable);
for (int i = 0; i < variable; i++)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    var dict = logic.TransformListInDictionary(list);

    //some code
    var task = Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            try
            {
                //some code

                await Task.Delay(randomSecundForPause.Next(100000, 150000)); // This is better because the thread is not blocked
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //some code

                await Task.Delay(randomSecundForPause.Next(100000, 150000));
            }
        }
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Notice that the `Dictionary` class is thread-safe for multiple readers, but not for multiple writers, so depending on what `//some code` does you might want to consider a `ConcurrentDictionary`.